# What is the difference between discord.py and discord.py rewrite? And are they both compatible with discord.py[voice]?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am a Senior High School IEA student and I am trying to develop a discord bot for a project. It is in my interest for the bot to have robust functions and have the capability to play music. I've glanced across multiple tutorials on youtube and I still find myself scratching my head.

Whats the difference between discord.py and discord.py rewrite?

Are you supposed to pip install discord.py[voice] separately from those two?

Is discord.py[voice] compatible with discord.py rewrite? Or is there a different version of voice on rewrite?

Also is there a specific IDE that you particularly recommend using for developing a discord bot?

Some clarity would be nice!

Comment: Due to the API changes of Discord (rolling out in April 2022) there have been a few changes. One consequence of the changes made by Discord is the discordpy project ending. The creator and maintainer of discordpy has written a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Rapptz/4a2f62751b9600a31a0d3c78100287f1) about why he stops the project instead of implementing the changes. I highly recommend to read it. I am unable to find the rewrite you mentioned. I also don't know about the impact of the changes on the discordpy[voice].

Comment: Discord.py rewrite refers to the rewrite of the library which was done over 3 years ago. The discord.py that you download now basically is discord.py rewrite. discord.py[voice] is just the normal library but with voice chat support. As @LoneLunatic mentioned, the project has beeen halted, however there are already promising forks of discord.py around. I would take a look at either nextcord or pycord.

Comment: I'm gonna have to sadly vote to close this question since it's not really following the guidelines, asking for software recommendations and general software support as well as asking multiple questions in one is off-topic, take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), if you're interested however there's the [discord.py](https://discord.gg/dpy) discord server where you can ask for help.

Comment: Łukasz Kwieciński. Oh. I apologize! I'm a new member and wasn't quite sure how it worked. I'll be more careful next time! I appreciate you being polite about it and even providing links. Some people can be very hostile. I'll read it over! Thanks again for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

discord.py is now up to date, so it will work fine for the project. I believe (I haven't worked with it before) discord.py[voice] is just a superset of discord.py with audio functionality, so installing it should leave you all set for your project.

As for an IDE, I recommend visual studio code or pycharm, this part isn't really important, just pick an editor that you like, get used to it, and it will get the job done fine.

Also, it's worth noting that mainline development for discord.py has recently ended, this shouldn't affect your project because it's a very recent change, but keep this in mind in the future in case things start to become incompatible.